# Error: bad signature/ fatal: index file corrupt when using git

Tags: git, github

I start my computer and then go to my project.
I type: `git status`

```
$ git status
error: bad signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

I try to fix with the way

```
del .git\index
git reset
```

after that, typing `gitk`, I see the error:

> Unknown revision HEAD

It still works properly the previous day. Is there any way to fix this, instead of cloning project from repo?

Comment: What does ```git status``` say after you executed this ```del .git\index; 
git reset``` ?

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari **git status** still shows a number of files and folders in untracked status (in red color)

Comment: Could you try `erase /s .git\index` and `erase .git\index.lock` followed by `git reset --keep` which is safe.

Comment: @ArcotDeepika: erase: command not found. I'm using window os

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, please share it. I also got the same problem.

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy Not yet